# How to find the longest common substring

Tags: algorithm

What is the best available algorithm to search the longest common substring? Strings contains 16000+ characters and alphabet is ACDT.

1. Boyer–Moore–Horspool - time taken is very high
2. Rabin-Karp - worst than 1st one
3. Suffix tree - 2d array memory overflow

Any other methods or modifications? Actually I want to calculate the average common substring of two genomes.

Comment: What about KMP? The methods you mentioned and one I mentioned are for searching a string in a string.

Comment: There are several improvements over plain Suffix Arrays: Compressed Suffix Arrays. You may utilize [Wavelet-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_Tree) or [FM-Indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM-index). Just search for them together with genomes and you'll find many papers.

Answer (score 1):

Gnomes or genomes?!

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). Dynamic programming may be the route to take?

Also note that the first two algorithms you've listed are for string searching.

Comment: genomes, but the 2d array which will be used in suffiz tree is very large.

Comment: Use the dynamic programming method. Will produce an array of size m * n, where m and n are the lengths of the two input strings. If you're still having memory issues, try converting to a smaller primitive type (such as a byte), since your alphabet is small?

Comment: Probably a good idea to edit your question then - at the moment you're asking about gnomes! :)

Comment: 1s and 0s will be stored in array. array size will be// array[string1.length()][[string1.length()] how about storing the array on a text file

Comment: Apologies, I've read the pseudocode a bit more. The dimensions of the array are the string lengths, the values are going to be integers from 0 to the length of the shortest string. Even so, memory usage is going to be about 488MB (2 * 16000 * 16000 / 1024 / 1024). You can increase the amount of memory available to with the following command line argument: '-Xmx1024m' (for example, to allow for 1GB).

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked in that way. but computation time is too large than horsepool. I can't believe it though.